# Setting Restsharp parameters

Tags: c#, http-post, restsharp

I've been going around in a circle with this.  I am attempting to make a post with *Restsharp*.  The problem is either I get an error about `application/xml` as the only allowed format or no content allowed in the prolog. In the below example if I use `AddBody()` then I will get the error about `application/xml` (in the watch for the request object I see the body is populated as `text/xml`), if I do the `AddParameter()` with `ParameterType.RequestBody` then I get the error about content in the prolog. I am having a hard time it seems controlling or even precisely what is being sent in the post.

```
var client = new RestClient("https://portfoliomanager.energystar.gov/wstest/");
var request = new RestRequest("{token}", Method.POST);

meterConsumptionType meteruse = new meterConsumptionType();

account newuser = new account();

// Populating object
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");

request.Parameters.Clear();
request.AddParameter("application/xml", newuser, ParameterType.RequestBody);

//request.AddBody(newuser);
request.AddUrlSegment("token", "account");

request.Parameters[1].ContentType = "application/xml";

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line to change the serializer:

request.XmlSerializer.ContentType = "application/xml";